# What am i doing wrong with programming this SUVAT

Tags: c++, math

I am writing this software for A-Level maths and im doing the mechanics section and i am doing a suvat with just the UVA figures, i need to find the S and i dont have T. So i re-arranged v^2=u^2+2as to get (v^2-u^2)/2a=s but i just dont get the right answer! what is wrong :L
.
.
.

```
if(selection == "1") {
float s,u,v,a,t;
cout<<"What is the value of U (Initial Velocity)" << endl;
cin >> u;
cout<<"What is the value of V (Final Velocity)" << endl;
cin >> v;
cout<<"What is the value of A (Acceleration)" << endl;
cin >> a;

s = (pow(2,v) - pow(2,u))/ (2*a);

cout << "The Value of S is "<< s << ". Dont forget unit!";
i++;
}
```

.
.
.
.

Answer (score 3):

You've mixed the arguments to [`pow`](http://www.kev.pulo.com.au/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cmath/pow.html) up. You're actually doing:

```
float vsq = pow(2, v); /* 2^v */
cout << vsq << endl;
```

Per the definition of `pow(x,y)`:

> Returns the value of `x` raised to the power of `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in using `pow` function. 
To express v^2 you need to use `pow(v,2)`.

So your calculation should be:

```
s = (pow(v,2) - pow(u,2))/ (2*a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for the order of the pow function parameters!!

You could simply do:

```
    cout<<"the value of s is"<< (pow(v,2) - pow(u,2))/ (2*a)<<".Dont forget unit!";
    // (v^2 - u^2) /2a
```